# How to issue HTTP POST request?

Tags: php, curl

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'message=Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed
```

The documentation says I need to issue one to publish to the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In php use the curl* family of functions.

an example:

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/arjun/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('access_token' => 'my token',
                                           'message' => 'Hello, Arjun. I like this new API.'));

curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: you also need to set header for https. I get the code working after setting these 2 options  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);

Answer (score 4):

It's worth mentioning that MANCHUCK's suggestion to use cURL is not the best way for this functionality as cURL is a not a core PHP extension. Administrators have to compile/enable it manually and it may not be available on all hosts. And as already pointed out on my blog - [PHP has native support for POSTing data](http://simas.posterous.com/posting-data-without-curl-extension) starting with PHP 4.3 version (released 8 years ago!).

```
// Your POST data
$data = http_build_query(array(
    'param1' => 'data1',
    'param2' => 'data2'
));

// Create HTTP stream context
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $data
    )
));

// Make POST request
$response = file_get_contents('http://example.com', false, $context);
```