# Consuming a Datasnap Server with PHP passing JSONObject as parameter

Tags: php, web-services, delphi, json, datasnap

I have a Datasnap Server and a have a method named :

```
function TServerMethodsMain.AddCity( ACity : TJSONObject ) : Boolean ;
```

I did small php code below to invoke this method.

```
<?php

class city
{
   public $id;
   public $description;
   public $uf;          
}

$objcity = new city ;

$objcity -> id          = 1         ;
$objcity -> description = 'MY CITY' ;
$objcity -> uf          = 'XX'      ;

$url  = 'http://192.168.1.101:8088/datasnap/rest/TServerMethodsMain/AddCity/' ;
$url .= json_encode( $objcity ) ;

$page = file($url) ;  

$show = json_decode($page[0]);

echo '<pre>';

print_r ($show);

echo '</pre>';

?>
```

I got this error message from browser (Firefox or IE) :

> Warning:
>   file(http://192.168.1.101:8088/datasnap/rest/TServerMethodsMain/AddCity/{"id":1,"description":"MY
>   CITY","uf":"XX"}) [function.file]:
>   failed to open stream: HTTP request
>   failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server
>   Error in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\json-php\index.php on
>   line 19

Well, I have others methods that works fine with this php code, but only if I pass as parametrer **Primitive Types** : String, Integer...

I did a debug and see that problem happens at moment I need to convert parameter **JSONObject** into **Object** ( **unMarshalll** ). When I invoke this method by Client Delphi Win32 it works fine !

Does anybody knows anything about the problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow below a link with my answer

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Talk:DataSnap_REST_Messaging_Protocol

Answer (score 1):

Your PHP code issue a GET request to the datasnap server. For complex parameters like JSONObject you need to use POST or PUT HTTP verb with proper JSONObject as message body.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DataSnap_REST_Messaging_Protocol#Parameters_in_the_URL

So, you need to send a POST request to the datasnap server. Check the documentations for further details.
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/DataSnap_REST_Messaging_Protocol

Comment: Hi Daniele Teti
First, thanks for replying !
Well, I dont know about web programming..ok
I did a mini framewrok to operate with client Web and Desktop. With Desktop all works normally... I just need to do some test with another clients (not RAD PHP). Could help me completing my example code?

thank you very much

Comment: I'm not on my work PC, so I cannot test it, but the code should looks like the following: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084834/how-to-issue-http-post-request

ASAP I'll post someting here and in my blog (www.danieleteti.it)

Comment: Ok Daniele, thanks again ! I will try some codes here !
ASAP post here something here or in your blok..ok

Answer (score 1):

This **PHP Code** works with **DataSnap - Delphi XE2**

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json", "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'user:pass');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $param_url);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```