# Sending Dual Forms with one submit, while pulling the email field from first Form into the second

Tags: javascript, php, forms, submission

I have two forms I need to send - the first form is a PHP mailer that takes the info from a bunch of fields and mails it to a recipent.  That form has a checkbox and if checked I need the email from that for to be sent via ANOTHER form to a list server adding them to mailing list.  I need all this to happen when clicking the submit button from the first form.  Can anyone help me with a solution. Thanks.

Form

```
<form class="form_1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate()">
<div class="field">
<div class="text2">
              <input type="text" id="name" value="<?php echo $_POST['name'];?>" name="name" title="Name" />
            </div>
            <!--text2-->
            <div class="req">*</div>
            <!--req--> 
          </div>
          <!--field-->
          <div class="field field_right">
            <div class="text2">
              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_POST['email'];?>"  title="Email" />
            </div>
            <!--text2-->
            <div class="req">*</div>
            <!--req--> 
          </div>
```

Sign-up for newsletter 
                
                 
              
              
              
                
                  Upload Resume:

```
          <div class="clearer"></div>
          <br />
          <div class="field">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn3" />
          </div>
          <!--field-->
        </form>
```

---

Form 2

```
<form action="http://www.example.com/mailing_list.html" method="post" name="xxxxxxx" onSubmit="return (!(UPTvalidateform(document.UPTmxxxxxx)));">
<input type="hidden" name="submitaction" value="3">
<input type="hidden" name="mlid" value="xxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="siteid" value="xxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="tagtype" value="q2">
<input type="hidden" name="demographics" value="-1">
<input type="hidden" name="redirection" value="http://www.xxxx.com/thankyou.php">
<input type="hidden" name="uredirection" value="http://">
<input type="hidden" name="welcome" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="double_optin" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="append" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="update" value="on">
<input type="hidden" name="activity" value="submit">

<tr><td colspan="2"></td></tr><tr><td> </td><td> <div class="text1"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" />

</div></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="send" value="send" class="button1"></button></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably need to do the second submission using [PHPs `curl` wrapper](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) so that you only have one form for the user to fill in. Is there any reason you must have two forms?

So it would work like this:

1. User submits form
2. Code sends first email
3. If checkbox checked then submit `curl` request to second form
4. Complete

A recent SO answers contains a simple intro to the curl post request process: [How to issue HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084834/how-to-issue-http-post-request/3084893#3084893)

Answer (score 1):

On your form, have the button tie back to a javascript event

```
<input type = 'button' value='Submit!' onclick='submitForms()' />
```

Then have that javascript function, submitForms, actually submit both of your forms.

```
    document.forms["form1"].submit();
    document.forms["form2"].submit();
```

Comment: This relies on the browser to issue both requests. Generally a browser will only action one request at a time. So can this method be relied upon cross browser to work? Without testing it I would imagine that the call to submit the second form would halt the first forms submission.

Comment: That's true. I suppose you could do the same with some fancy AJAX, but your suggestion of using CURL is probably more elegant, assuming the OP has or can make CURL available.