# How can I easily make a POST from inside PHP code?

Tags: php, http-post

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP + curl, HTTP POST sample code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138527/php-curl-http-post-sample-code)
>   [POST data to URL php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-url-php)
>   [How to issue HTTP POST request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3084834/how-to-issue-http-post-request)

I've created a script that intercepts a regular post, and based on the username does one thing or another.

In one of the conditional branches, I want to move the user along and POST what he wrote down in the login form to another PHP script.

How can I easily make a POST request to a URL?

Is there something like:

```
$data = array("username" => "admin", "password" => "hunter2");

http_post("foo.com", "POST", $data);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please search before asking. There are [many, many questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+post+to+url) that answer this directly.

Comment: Is there a library that REALLY abstracts this away for me? cURL seems like overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
// Create map with request parameters
$params = array ('surname' => 'Filip', 'lastname' => 'Czaja');

// Build Http query using params
$query = http_build_query ($params);

// Create Http context details
$contextData = array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'header' => "Connection: close\r\n".
                        "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n",
            'content'=> $query );

// Create context resource for our request
$context = stream_context_create (array ( 'http' => $contextData ));

// Read page rendered as result of your POST request
$result =  file_get_contents (
              'http://www.sample-post-page.com',  // page url
              false,
              $context);

// Server response is now stored in $result variable so you can process it
```

source:
http://fczaja.blogspot.ch/2011/07/php-how-to-send-post-request-with.html

Comment: This looks better than cURl, at least easier to read. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well done!!! Easy steps! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

That's what the curl functions exist for. See, for example: http://davidwalsh.name/curl-post